# how to install google or-tools for python on Ubuntu in terminal?

Tags: python, or-tools

I cannot download Python—tar.gz (all platforms) from https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/installing
any one help me how to install google or-tools for python on Ubuntu in terminal?

Comment: In case `pip` is installed: `pip install ortools`. If `pip` is not installed: install it first.

Comment: @Klaus D hello I had try to install it but the following error has been issued
 "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ortools (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for ortools"
how can I solve it?

Comment: How can I install ortools without pip? I need to download all the libraries pass it to the cybersecurity department and then they let me install it